# Adjusting Sliding Div Height to 100% for Full Background Coverage on Hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I'm looking to adjust the height of a sliding div to occupy 100% of its container. This entails having the background image fully cover the div on hover. Could someone kindly guide me on how to achieve this?
Below is the current code I'm working with:
Here is a screenshot that shows how to remove the gap/or increase the height of the sliding div on hover.
[image]

```css
      .collections {
  padding: 90px 0 0 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

  .collections .heading-container h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 38px;
  color: #28326e;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: "Mulish", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 40px 0;
}

  .collections .slide-animation-wrapper #slide1 {
  background: url("https://media.cmsmax.com/d3xadgynuglafnjbqq2la/double-hung-the-wonder-wood.jpg") no-repeat center center transparent;
}
  .collections .slide-animation-wrapper #slide2 {
  background: url("https://media.cmsmax.com/d3xadgynuglafnjbqq2la/double-hung-the-wonder-window.jpg") no-repeat center center transparent;
}
  .collections .slide-animation-wrapper #slide3 {
  background: url("https://media.cmsmax.com/d3xadgynuglafnjbqq2la/double-hung-the-wonder-star.jpg") no-repeat center center transparent;
}
  .collections .slide-animation-wrapper #slide4 {
  background: url("https://media.cmsmax.com/d3xadgynuglafnjbqq2la/double-hung-the-wonder-choice.jpg") no-repeat center center transparent;
}
  .collections .slide-animation-wrapper #slide5 {
  background: url("https://media.cmsmax.com/d3xadgynuglafnjbqq2la/double-hung-our-saver.jpg") no-repeat center center transparent;
}
  .collections .slide-animation-wrapper #slide6 {
  background: url("https://media.cmsmax.com/d3xadgynuglafnjbqq2la/double-hung-price-beater-plus.jpg") no-repeat center center transparent;
}
  .collections .slide-animation-wrapper .slide-wrapper {
  background-size: cover !important;
  height: 430px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

  .collections .slide-animation-wrapper .slide-wrapper::before {
  display: block;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
  .collections .slide-animation-wrapper .slide-wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  width: 100%;
}
  .collections .slide-animation-wrapper .slide-wrapper .slide-text {
  bottom: 0px;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: top 0.1s ease 0s;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}
  .collections .slide-animation-wrapper .slide-wrapper .slide-text .slide-heading {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
  .collections .slide-animation-wrapper .slide-wrapper .slide-text .slide-heading h4 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 38px;
  color: #28326e;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: "Mulish", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
  .collections .slide-animation-wrapper .slide-wrapper .slide-text .slide-body {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
}
  .collections .slide-animation-wrapper .slide-wrapper .slide-text .slide-body .button-wrapper {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
  .collections .slide-animation-wrapper .slide-wrapper .slide-text .slide-body P {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: #58585a;
  font-family: "Mulish", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
  .collections .slide-animation-wrapper .slide-wrapper .slide-text img {
  transition: opacity 0.1s ease 0s;
  max-width: 100%;
}
  .collections .slide-animation-wrapper .slide-wrapper:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
  .collections .slide-animation-wrapper .slide-wrapper:hover .slide-body {
  max-height: 960px;
  opacity: 1;
}
  .collections .slide-animation-wrapper .slide-wrapper:hover .slide-heading img {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>

<body>



    <section class="collections">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="heading-container">
                <h1>Collections</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 g-1">

                    <div class="slide-animation-wrapper">
                        <div class="slide-wrapper" id="slide1">
                            <div class="slide-text">
                                <div class="slide-heading">
                                    <h4>The Wonder Wood</h4>
                                    <img src="https://media.cmsmax.com/d3xadgynuglafnjbqq2la/double-hung-arrow-right.png"
                                        alt="double-hung-arrow">
                                </div>
                                <div class="slide-body">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                        tempor
                                        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
                                        nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                        consequat.
                                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                                        eu
                                        fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>

                                    <div class="button-wrapper my-4">
                                        <a href=""
                                            class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-blue-border-white-color btn-blue-border-white-color--lg">Learn
                                            More</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 g-1">

                    <div class="slide-animation-wrapper">
                        <div class="slide-wrapper" id="slide2">
                            <div class="slide-text">
                                <div class="slide-heading">
                                    <h4>The Wonder Window</h4>
                                    <img src="https://media.cmsmax.com/d3xadgynuglafnjbqq2la/double-hung-arrow-right.png"
                                        alt="double-hung-arrow">
                                </div>
                                <div class="slide-body">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                        tempor
                                        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
                                        nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                        consequat.
                                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                                        eu
                                        fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                                    <div class="button-wrapper my-4">
                                        <a href=""
                                            class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-blue-border-white-color btn-blue-border-white-color--lg">Learn
                                            More</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 g-1">

                    <div class="slide-animation-wrapper">
                        <div class="slide-wrapper" id="slide3">
                            <div class="slide-text">
                                <div class="slide-heading">
                                    <h4>The Wonder Star</h4>
                                    <img src="https://media.cmsmax.com/d3xadgynuglafnjbqq2la/double-hung-arrow-right.png"
                                        alt="double-hung-arrow">
                                </div>
                                <div class="slide-body">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                        tempor
                                        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
                                        nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                        consequat.
                                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                                        eu
                                        fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                                    <div class="button-wrapper my-4">
                                        <a href=""
                                            class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-blue-border-white-color btn-blue-border-white-color--lg">Learn
                                            More</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 g-1">

                    <div class="slide-animation-wrapper">
                        <div class="slide-wrapper" id="slide4">
                            <div class="slide-text">
                                <div class="slide-heading">
                                    <h4>The Wonder Choice</h4>
                                    <img src="https://media.cmsmax.com/d3xadgynuglafnjbqq2la/double-hung-arrow-right.png"
                                        alt="double-hung-arrow">
                                </div>
                                <div class="slide-body">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                        tempor
                                        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
                                        nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                        consequat.
                                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                                        eu
                                        fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                                    <div class="button-wrapper my-4">
                                        <a href=""
                                            class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-blue-border-white-color btn-blue-border-white-color--lg">Learn
                                            More</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 g-1">

                    <div class="slide-animation-wrapper">
                        <div class="slide-wrapper" id="slide5">
                            <div class="slide-text">
                                <div class="slide-heading">
                                    <h4>Our Saver</h4>
                                    <img src="https://media.cmsmax.com/d3xadgynuglafnjbqq2la/double-hung-arrow-right.png"
                                        alt="double-hung-arrow">
                                </div>
                                <div class="slide-body">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                        tempor
                                        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
                                        nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                        consequat.
                                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                                        eu
                                        fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                                    <div class="button-wrapper my-4">
                                        <a href=""
                                            class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-blue-border-white-color btn-blue-border-white-color--lg">Learn
                                            More</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 g-1">

                    <div class="slide-animation-wrapper">
                        <div class="slide-wrapper" id="slide6">
                            <div class="slide-text">
                                <div class="slide-heading">
                                    <h4>Price Beater Plus</h4>
                                    <img src="https://media.cmsmax.com/d3xadgynuglafnjbqq2la/double-hung-arrow-right.png"
                                        alt="double-hung-arrow">
                                </div>
                                <div class="slide-body">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                        tempor
                                        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
                                        nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                        consequat.
                                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                                        eu
                                        fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                                    <div class="button-wrapper my-4">
                                        <a href=""
                                            class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-blue-border-white-color btn-blue-border-white-color--lg">Learn
                                            More</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </section>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So, this kind of thing: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7jhb0k81/1/?

Comment: @DavidThomas yes thank you so much you are right. can you help me to edit my code to make same thing ?

Answer (score 1):

You've to replace this in your css:

```
.collections .slide-animation-wrapper .slide-wrapper .slide-text .slide-body {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
}


.collections .slide-animation-wrapper .slide-wrapper:hover .slide-body {
  height: 350px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

and that's it

Example in Codepen:
https://codepen.io/Leonardo-Saenz/pen/bGzbVRR

Comment: Thank you so much Leonardo for your help. it works.
thumbs up...